# Add a Native Calendar with Titanium

Tags: javascript, android, titanium, appcelerator, android-calendar

For an app developed in Titanium, it is required to be possible to add Events into the Native Android Calendar. While the docs specify plenty of methods to add Events to the native calendar (selectable ones), it does not provide the methods to create a new Calendar (conceptually a layer that holds events)

Has anyone been able to create a new Calendar on Android and how, specifically on Titanium, can one do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a new calendar for Android is not currently supported in Titanium. Here's the link to the ticket in their issue list.

https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-5930

Comment: Its sad when you have to mark a "you can't" type of answer as the correct one :(. Thank you @Michael

Comment: I'd definitely bump the ticket up and see if you can get any update on it, they are usually pretty good at answering and letting people know. Otherwise if you know the Android API you can port the method across and put a pull request in yourself if it's critical.