# Titanium, add event to calendar on android

Tags: android, calendar, titanium

I'm trying to add an event to the Calendar on Android Phone. Ti.Calendar.defaultCalendar is only available on iOS so I have to ask the user to select the calendar to add the event to. I use Ti.Calendar.allCalendars() to get all calendars. The resulting list also contains not editable calendars. If the users selects one of these and the app tries to add the event then the app completely crashes. Also with a try{}catch{} the app crashes. 
Is it possible to get only editable calendars or is there another solution to prevent the app from crashing?

The code I'm using comes from the documentation:
http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Calendar

CLI Version:5.0.9; SDK Version:5.4.0.GA;

Answer (score 0):

At the time of posting this functionality still isn't available on Android for Titanium unfortunately. https://stackoverflow.com/a/37816867/2132015